# How Do I Fix This Run.bat thing For Minecraft Bukkit Servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I followed [Bukkit.org's steps](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server):

1. Create a folder with your choice of names
2. Download the latest recommended build CraftBukkit.Jar
3. Place the Craftbukkit1.5.2 jar from step 2 in your folder
4. Rename CraftBukkit1.5.2-R1.0.Jar To CraftBukkit.jar
5. Open Notepad and copy and paste `java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
   PAUSE`
6. Save the Notepad text you just wrote and click save-as (Name).Bat (I did run.bat too.  It still didn't work .)
7. Double-Click Run.bat or (Name).bat and it should load your world

[Step 7 Error Please Read]:  I opened up Run.bat and it is in the same file as craftbukkit.jar Which is the folder I made.  It is right below craftbukkit.jar and I open up Run.bat and this crap showed up.

[image: Cropped screenshot says, "Error unable to access jarfile craftbukkit.jar"]

Comment: It's hard to read your screenshot, but I think that it says that you are running Windows.  Which one?  XP, Vista, 7?

Comment: I think that you named your folder (step 1):  Bukkit Server Minecraft.  Is that correct?  Can you post a higher resolution screenshot of the contents of that folder?  And if it had a better view of the window that you get from double-clicking run.bat, that would be great too.

Comment: Brythan how did you edit that? It was rejecting my edit.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 Somebody approved it.

Comment: @Liam Badey You should attempt using the Fully Qualifed Path to the jar. I.E. `C:\\Users\\Liam\\.minecraft\\Bukkit\\bukkit.jar`

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108  And someone (two people actually) rejected yours as being an answer rather than an edit.  If you click your username; then Activity; then Suggestions; then Suggested Edit (next to this question), you can see the rejection messages.

Comment: Could you please run a dir command in the folder with the craftbukkit jar and copy-paste the output? Also, don't reply to answers by editing your question; use comments on the answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

You've almost certainly named it `craftbukkit.jar.jar` instead of `craftbukkit.jar`, due to Windows hiding file extensions from you. Remove the visible `.jar` from the file name (the hidden `.jar` will still be there) and the script should work.

Comment: To add on, you should probably turn on file extensions, just to make it less confusing.

Comment: In case you don't know how to turn on file extensions, Press the Alt key then click tools then folder options. Click the view tab and uncheck `Hide file extensions for known file types`. You will now be able to see the file extensions recommended by Jeffrey Lin.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Craft Bukkit 1.5.2 Try this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true